# Any better way to purge the inactive memory?

Tags: macos, performance

Running purge command in the terminal to free the inactive memory isn't really what I think about Apple.

Lion isn't doing a great at all when it comes to free the inactive memory.
Free memory is reaching 16 MB and applications and the OS are becoming unresponsive, yet OS X isn't reclaiming the inactive memory.

After each session, I put the laptop to sleep. You can say that I shutdown my OS once a month.  Unixes after all aren't created to be rebooted.

OS X Snow Leopard was pretty sleek, I don't know but it looks it is a Lion thing (maybe due iOS brought to Lion features).

Any better way to reclaim the inactive memory on Lion?
[EDIT]
I got 4 GB of RAM

Comment: What's your system configuration?  If, for example, you're running 10.7 with 2GB of RAM, it's likely this behavior is unavoidable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Isn't Inactive memory a waste of resources?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/67031/isnt-inactive-memory-a-waste-of-resources)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, one command only (run in Terminal):

```
purge
```

And recheck inactive RAM

Comment: That is my first line :p

Answer (score 2):

The real way I've made progress diagnosing this sort of issue is to use `sysdiagnose` to profile your system immediately after boot, then again before swap starts to get written and again when you note the slowdown.

Issuing `purge` is not effective with OS X virtual memory on Lion and muddies the waters to find the real culprit in terms of memory leaks or paging stress.

I've found that server Macs are generally stable for 6 months or more and don't need reboots before an update will force a reboot. Client Macs running software like Office, Adobe and even some of Apple's consumer products (or Pro apps) do not run perpetually like other UNIX and benefit from a reboot once a month or so to clear memory if you have issues with swap that cannot be isolated and ameliorated by `sysdiagnose` or other changes in usage.

Comment: `sysdiagnose` isn't available on Snow Leopard. I'd say a busy client Mac desktop should be restarted more often than once/month, depending on how hard you are pushing it and how many apps you are using. I'm experimenting now with `purge` to see if it will do the same thing as a restart or a logout/login.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not much better than what you are doing but I use iboostup occasionally when i wan t to free up some memory.  I constantly struggling here with 2gb MBA and i use vmaware fusion for windows machine that just takes the memory from me. It has a couple other nice features too.

http://www.iboostup.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are free apps on the Mac App Store that add a free-memory button to the menu bar for quick memory purging.

Search for "memory" in the MAS and choose what suits your needs.

Hope this is what you are looking for.