# How to find memory leaking apps in OSX 10.6.8?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory-leak

I have an old 2008 MacBook with 4GB of memory. (Memory from About this Mac, everymac.com gave me a different number.) I know it's old, but it almost seems like it's slower than it should be. I have a lot of software so I was wondering, how could I easily find memory leaking processes?

Answer (score 1):

[Activity Monitor.app](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201464) indicates how much memory each process running on your Mac is using.

Comment: I know, but some are supposed to use that much memory. Some of them I need as well. Even after quitting them, it just gets worse again. I need to find specific apps that aren't handling memory well.

Answer (score 0):

To find apps which are using the most memory, try the following command in *Terminal*:

```
ps -awxm -o %mem,rss,comm | sort -nr | head
```

Also `top` command may help to monitor suspicious processes in real time.

In general OS X kernel (similar to others) is designed to use up all the available memory. See: [Isn't Inactive memory a waste of resources?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/67031/22781) for more details.

If you've limited amount of memory, consider quitting apps or closing browser tabs which you're not using. You can also find some *Memory Clean* apps which will try free up some memory when it's full.