# High memory usage on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, memory, catalina, activity-monitor

I noticed that most of the time, Activity Monitor tells me that memory used is above 10 Gb (out of 16). But the processes listed doesn't seem to consume as much memory.

Here are screenshots :
[image: Ordered By Real Memory]

[image: Ordered By Memory]

I also want to add that my macOS installation is quite clean (and recent). 
I don't expect a virus or something to be the origin of a high memory consumption.
This is a 2017 Macbook Pro 15" with macOS Catalina (10.15.2).

At the time the screenshots were taken, I was using Visual Studio Code for web programming with Chrome (12 tabs), Firefox (3 tabs), MySQLWorkBench with no script running, Trello, a 3 page Word document and a freshly created blank Excel spreadsheet.

Do you think it is normal ?

Comment: Your screenshot is cut off at right but I'm quite sure there are is a scrollbar at the right hand side and more processes further down. And there is no memory pressure at all, so it's not really clear what you mean by "high memory consumption".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - your Mac is perfectly normal and here's how to tell precisely how much extra RAM you can allocate to reach pre-designed limits that Apple has established for macOS.

- no swap (which isn't a problem either, just if you wait for swapping then it's a problem)
- no memory pressure
- all memory should get allocated since unused RAM is a waste the system is designed to allocate it all and if it cannot, you purchased too much RAM.

You’ve provided very excellent details and thinking in this analysis. Overall, everything looks to be functioning perfectly, well allocating memory to all the programs you have, zero memory pressure, the compression routine is starting to kick in - you have a very balanced amount of wired to application-specific memory.

I wouldn’t worry a bit and this looks exactly like a normal system running in balance with excess RAM available for you to add significant more programs or data processing.

All UNIX type operating systems are designed to keep in RAM all the data it can and minimize the amount of free memory since it can release the allocations instantly when a new use is higher priority than the old cached data that can is there just in case:

- [Isn't Inactive memory a waste of resources?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/67031/isnt-inactive-memory-a-waste-of-resources)
- https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/12/03/how-much-memory-is-my-process-using-/

Basically, the memory system has many layers of physical and logical abstractions that let it commit what looks to be a poor allocation on first glance that in practice is efficient, speedy and very well tested in practice.

When you would start to worry about not enough memory, the system will draw the pressure chart in yellow and red. Even running there can be just fine, it only means you can’t add more memory hungry processes, and not that you’re actually being slowed due to pressure.

- [What scale or measure does Mavericks' and Yosemite's "memory pressure" adhere to?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107126/what-scale-or-measure-does-mavericks-and-yosemites-memory-pressure-adhere-to)

From the above link, you can convince yourself how much extra memory you have ready to go by artificially running a command to over-allocate memory until you reach the warning level (or the critical level). Here are screen shots of my MacBook that runs every bit as fast when over-allocated to critical - everything is as snappy in Safari / Photos / whatever as it is with zero memory pressure.

[image: green memory pressure shown in Activity Monitor]

The above image is everything going back to green after running the critical command and pressing control+C (or closing the terminal window running the memory_pressure diagnostic.

```
sudo memory_pressure -l warn
sudo memory_pressure -l critical
```

Here are the images after warning and critical - you can see how much allocation was needed to push the system to these thresholds:

[image: warning = yellow memory pressure shown in Activity Monitor]

[image: critical = red memory pressure shown in Activity Monitor]

So, on my Mac that only has 8 GB of RAM, I needed to allocate another 4.65 GB of memory to reach the "warning" state and another 6.46 GB of memory to reach the "critical" state where there's no longer an abundance of free memory for the next use. Even then, the system was not slowed any perceptible amount. Pretty amazing for an m3 chip running 1.1 GHz or so that was build 5 years ago.

[image: MacBook One - I love this Mac so]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I've just added up the values listed in activity monitor until the process takes less than 80mb and the sum is ~7.8 Gb. I'm worried because I know this current work load on my Mac isn't the heavier I can give. (sometimes I need more apps open) and I wonder if I "have" to buy a 32gb Mac.. (I don't want to tbh, too expensive)

Comment: No, your system will adjust - it over allocates to use all RAM it has, not that it needs the RAM it allocates. You will see the pressure get to Yellow and Red when you need to consider more RAM if you can’t change the software running. Let me see if I can link to some memory pressure posts for you... @Hellcat8 [This One](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/242344) needs an update to be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the details, really appreciated. So I've run the memory_pressure commands (warning and crit) -> is it normal that it takes some time ? As the RAM is supposed to be really fast, I expected the additionnal allocation would be rather.. immediate ? I have to say, when in warning, the system freezes here and there for like 1s (specially when switching desktops). Once the critical state reached, I hit Ctrl+C and the memory used dropped to 4,4 Gb.. instead of 11-12. So if I understand correctly, about 7gb was allocated to "just-in-case" apps things ?

Comment: @Hellcat8 The program could drop all the RAM and crash the system so it loads the ship slowly and carefully to measure it in equilibrium. Also, virtual memory makes changes and adjustments - it's a reactive system and shocks need time to propagate and reach a steady state. That pause would be your system swapping things out and then paging them in - totally normal. What was the value in Memory column for the memory_pressure - that's the number (see my text and my screen shots)

Comment: Sorry I've seen that part of your post after the first execution of these commands. So I've run them again : 9.3Gb in warning state and 12,3Gb in critical state.

Comment: You have so much free memory still, no way you’ll need 32 for quite some expansion of need. @Hellcat8 - everything I suspected is confirmed by your testing. The system only needs 4 GB of space to run your current load - the rest is cached and lightly used storage.

Comment: Okay good to know ! Thanks a lot for your time and happy new year :)

Answer (score 1):

My mac is using also quite a lot of memory. I am running just few programs, far from my heavy tasks and I have 32GB and my system is using 22GB. But memory pressure graph is low green line so it looks like that it manage memory differently than e.g. windows. On windows I have a problem to reach over 16GB so I think windows is cleaning ram when possible, MacOS most probably keeps stuff in memory until it is really needed somewhere else.