# Can I run 2 16 Gig ram in my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, performance

I am looking to increase the ram in myMacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) 2.5 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7.

```
BANK 1/DIMM0:

Size:   8 GB
Type:   DDR3
Speed:  1600 MHz

Manufacturer:   0x80AD
Part Number:    0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
 
BANK 0/DIMM0:

Size:   8 GB
Type:   DDR3
Speed:  1600 MHz

Manufacturer:   0x80AD
Part Number:    0x484D54343147533642465238412D50422020
```

I want to upgrade to 32gig can I do that and what do you recommend I use and where should I get it?

Comment: If you want to pop a second question showing your memory pressure from activity monitor and what your performance goals are, we might have some advice. Most of our graphic intensive macs are happy with 8 on Mojave and newer and very few (couple percent of the fleet) need more than 16 RAM.

Comment: I use clean my Mac monitor panel and 9 out of 10 times it's informing me I need to free up memory.  I would need some coaching to get what you are asking me for, Thanks Don

Comment: I accept that challenge. Would you read this post and tell me if it’s way too complicated / needs to be summarized or just needs an edit to be useful? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/242415/5472 I will edit that answer based on your feed back and if you want to ask “How would I do a check to see how my apps use memory on macOS Mojave / Catalina (whichever you prefer)?” I’ll make you an answer to that question and link to the more technical post if needed.

Comment: I’m thinking I don’t want to go into `vmstat` and virtual machines unless you are using them as part of why you want an upgrade. I think a new question would be better to help you get started on measuring RAM to get advice and make decisions.

Answer (score 1):

[Everymac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.5-15-dual-graphics-mid-2015-retina-display-specs.html) says no.

The RAM is soldered to the motherboard & cannot be changed.

> 16 GB of RAM is onboard and cannot be upgraded to a higher capacity at the initial time of system purchase or later.