# Suggestions to make a old Macbook Pro faster?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, software-recommendation, performance, macos

I got a Macbook Pro I think the year 2010. How can I make it faster because,it starting to get slow. Are there Free or Inexpensive Apps or tricks to make it fast?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  What is the current version of the OS on your MacBook Pro?  Go to the  > About this Mac to see.  You should also be able to determine the model year from here.

Comment: Thanks! I have Yosemite but, I will update soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a clean install to El Capitan

> Make your Mac run silent, cool and fast under OS X El Capitan
>   http://9to5mac.com/2015/10/16/how-to-make-your-mac-run-silent-cool-fast-os-x-el-capitan/

use CleanMyMac 3 to optimize & clean your mac

> Clean, optimize, and maintain your Mac with CleanMyMac 3. It scans
>   every inch of your system, runs maintenance tasks, and keeps an eye on
>   your Mac’s health.
>   http://macpaw.com

clean your RAM when your Mac is too slow

https://itunes.apple.com/app/memory-clean-monitor-free/id451444120?mt=12

and, more expensive; you can upgrade your RAM

> MacBook Pro 13" Unibody Mid 2010 RAM Replacement tutorial with iFixit
>   https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2010+RAM+Replacement/4319

or you can downgrade to Mavericks or lower (clean install too)

Comment: Thanks but, isn't cleanmymac bad from reviews?

Comment: I'm using CMM for a while and I really like it... I have not heard about bad reviews before. But you can test it and make your own opinion ;)

Comment: Empty RAM is wasted RAM. Mavericks wasn't so good at handling the new memory paradigm, but Yosemite & El Capitan have got a lot better - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/67031/isnt-inactive-memory-a-waste-of-resources/67048#67048 for a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I put a 260 GB Intel 530 Series SSD into my mid-2009 MacBook Pro and it did wonders for it, cut the boot-up time in half. Just get a good brand, my Intel hasn't had any problems

You could also upgrade the RAM. Other World Computing is a great place to buy RAM for your specific model of Mac.

My Mid-2009 MacBook Pro runs El Capitan pretty well, so you may as well update to it, as El Capitan is supposed to make Macs (even older models) run faster. That's my experience with El Capitan, but YMMV.

An SSD, RAM, and El Capitan is where I would start if I wanted to upgrade any Mac.

Comment: Hmm I would do that if I had the money but, thanks for the suggestion.